# Django: InlineModelAdmin to reference its own Model

Tags: django, inline, admin

So I am trying to setup an entry posting system, where the user can select a bunch of related entries when creating an entry. And it would be wonderful if I could use the InlineModelAdmin for it. But it keeps wanting a foreignkey, which for some reason I'm unable to set up properly.

Here's a simplified setup of my situation:

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry           =   models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='related_entry', null=True, blank=True)
    title           =   models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    description     =   models.TextField(verbose_name='description')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
class EntryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry
    verbose_name = "related entry"

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        EntryInline,
    ]    

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

The problems im getting are of the likes:

> DatabaseError at /admin/app/entry/add/
>   column app_entry.entry_id does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT "app_entry"."id",
>   "app_entry"."entry_id", "...

I'm still just kneedeep into the magic world of django, so if someone could point me out where I am going wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I tried the code you provided in my machine (Django 1.2.3, Python 2.6.2, Ubuntu Jaunty) and it worked well as far as I could tell.

> where the user can select a bunch of related entries when creating an entry.

Shouldn't you be using a `ManyToMany` relationship if you want an entry to be related to *a bunch of* entries? Your code currently defines a `ForeignKey` instead.

> admin.py
>
> ...
>
> admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)

Your admin is presently set up to let the user add an entry and also (optionally) one or more related entries in the same page (this worked perfectly). Was this your expectation?

Comment: yes that is what i want! then i guess should try to debug my somewhat more complex setup, if it works fine for you, hm.

Comment: ok it works, but it seems like i do have to go with a many to many :), thanks anyway!